# How to include reference at the end of beamer?

Tags: beamer, citing

I am using beamer to prepare my presentation, in that I want to include my selected reference at the end of each beamer. How can I do it in IEEE style?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Answer (score 5):

A quick example with `biblatex` (using http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{knuth:ct}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]